# Updating GUI on separate thread while other method is executing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a GUI that I have developed that has a couple of buttons and a JTextArea for output. I have some code below that executes a function and updates the TextArea, however before the function is executed I would like the TextArea to be updated with the string "`Processing...`", just to give the user some kind of idea that the application is working as the function takes a while to execute.

At the moment this code doesn't update the GUI element and I understand why. The GUI doesn't get a chance to repaint in between the two commands that change the TextArea, so the "processing..." string is never displayed. How do I change the code so that the GUI element updates before the Main.featureAnalysisTop() function executes?

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Extract Features"))
            {                   
                featuresTextArea.setText("Processing...");
                int nFeatures = nFeatureSlider.getValue(); 
                Main.featureAnalysisTop(nFeatures);

                featuresTextArea.setText("");
                ArrayList<String> featureList = Main.getFeatureList();

                for(String str : featureList)
                {
                        featuresTextArea.append(str + "\n");
                }
```

The GUI is executed in my main method using the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gui = new GUI2();
                    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    gui.frmNeuralNetwork.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete example? Right now, I have no idea what `GUI2` is and where and when your "extract features" code is called. And please do not dump your whole application, try to come up with a small main method that shows what you want to achieve. Furthermore, you might want to have a look at this: [Updating GUI from a runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365404/updating-gui-from-a-runnable)

Comment: As your question title suggests you need to use a separate Thread for running the other task so you don't prevent the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` from responding to events. The common way to do this is the use a `Swing Worker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the EDT and for an example of using a SwingWorker.

Answer (score 1):

> Updating GUI on separate thread while other method is executing

That's a job for the [Swing Woker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) class, which allows you to create a separate thread that runs in the background and lets you update your GUI accordingly.

For example, I made a simple example that accomplishes what you're trying to do.

First we create the GUI and add an `ActionListener` to our `JButton` where it starts our `Swing Worker` after updating the `JTextArea`'s text to `processing...` as you were trying to do it and after 5 seconds (which simulates your long running task) it updates to `I'm done!`.

You can try it and change the code accordingly.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class TextAreaUpdater {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JButton button;
    private SwingWorker<String, String> worker;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextAreaUpdater()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        area = new JTextArea(10, 30);

        button = new JButton("Update!");
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); //Simulates long running task
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "I'm done!"; //Returns the text to be set on the JTextArea
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                super.done();
                try {
                    area.setText(get()); //Set the textArea the text given from the long running task
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ActionListener listener = (e -> {
        area.setText("Processing...");
        worker.execute(); //Initializes long running task
    });
}
```

References:

- [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)
- [How do I use SwingWorker in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)

Here's another example that uses `SwingWorker`: [update jlabel text after opening jdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256369/update-jlabel-text-after-opening-jdialog/42256976#42256976)

Hope it helps