# Unable to display panels in the changed frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working on a JAVA desktop application that has two frames, users clicks a button on frame 1, response based on the selected option would be updated to the database. While the response is being updated, frame 2 should be displayed.

If I set the frame 2 to visible before the database update, frame 2 is displayed but with empty content i.e panels of frame 2 are not displayed. But once the database update is completed, the contents of the frame are shown.

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                Utilities.updateToDB("clicked button1");    
            }
        });
```

Content of Frame 2 should be shown while the database update is taking place or before it.

Comment: I suggest that you check out JDesktopPane. If you still need help, please provide a more fleshed out example? See [mcve] for tips on creating a working example.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) *"Frame 2 should be shown while the database update is taking place or before it."* Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case I suggest you to use:

A [`Swing Worker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891172/updating-gui-on-separate-thread-while-other-method-is-executing/47891637#47891637) and the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Something along the lines:

```
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); //Simulates long running task (your database update)
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Updated"; //Returns the text to be set on your status JLabel once the update is done
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    super.done();
    try {
        // Here update your GUI or do whatever you want to do when the update is done.
        textfield.setText(get()); //Set to the textField the text given from the long running task
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And on your `ActionListener` something like:

```
private ActionListener listener = (e -> {
    frame2.setVisible(true); //suggested use of cardlayout and display nextCard here.
    worker.execute(); //Initializes long running task
});
```

However I suggest you not to use multiple `JFrames`: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) and use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517392/how-to-view-another-jpanel-containing-many-sub-jpanels-from-same-jframe-in-netbe/49519023#49519023)